# Read data from text format into Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, datasource

I am running Python 2.7 on Windows.

I have a large text file (2 GB) that refers to 500K+ emails. The file has no explicit file type and is in the format:

```
email_message#: 1
email_message_sent: 10/10/1991 02:31:01
From: tomf@abc.com| Tom Foo |abc company|
To: adee@abc.com| Alex Dee |abc company|
To: benfor12@xyz.com| Ben For |xyz company|
email_message#: 2
email_message_sent: 10/12/1991 01:28:12
From: timt@abc.com| Tim Tee |abc company|
To: tomf@abc.com| Tom Foo |abc company|
To: adee@abc.com| Alex Dee |abc company|
To: benfor12@xyz.com| Ben For|xyz company|
email_message#: 3
email_message_sent: 10/13/1991 12:01:16
From: benfor12@xyz.com| Ben For |xyz company|
To: tomfoo@abc.com| Tom Foo |abc company|
To: t212@123.com| Tatiana Xocarsky |numbers firm |
...
```

As you can see, each email has the following data associated with it:

1) the time it was sent

2) the email address who sent it

3) the name of the person who sent it

4) the company that person works for

5) every email address that received the email

6) the name of every person who received the email

7) the company of every person who received the email

In the text files there are 500K+ emails, and emails can have up to 16K recipients. There is no pattern in the emails in how they refer to names of people or the company they work at.

I would like to take this large file and manipulate it in `python` so that it ends up as a `Pandas` `Dataframe`. I would like the `pandas` `dataframe` in the format like the screenshot from `excel` below:

[image: Sample Data Structure]

**EDIT**

My plan to solve this is to write a "parser" that takes this text file and reads in each line, assigning the text in each line to a particular columns of a `pandas` `dataframe`.

I plan to write something like the below. Can someone confirm that this is the correct way to go about executing this? I want to make sure I am not missing a built-in `pandas` function or function from a different `module`.

```
#connect to object 
data = open('.../Emails', 'r')

#build empty dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

#function to read lines of the object and put pieces of text into the
# correct column of the dataframe
for line in data:
     n = data.readline()
    if n.startswith("email_message#:"):
        #put a slice of the text into a dataframe
    elif n.startswith("email_message_sent:"):
        #put a slice of the text into a dataframe
    elif n.startswith("From:"):
        #put slices of the text into a dataframe
    elif n.startswith("To:"):
        #put slices of the text into a dataframe
```

Comment: @whoever down-voted this question. Can you briefly explain why you down-voted it? I would appreciate even a point in the right direction on this issue

Comment: Sorry @BeeGee, I was distracted while I was at it. It would help to know  about your efforts and where you are actually struggling. Otherwise the only possible answer is to write the parser for you, which I do not think is the point. You're just writing some requirements and asking for the code. Other than that the question is clear and well written and I am willing to help.

Comment: @Goyo thank you for helping me with my question. I am going to write my own parser and will post my solution if there indeed is no module

Comment: No, if you are looking for a one liner for that job I do not think there is one, at least in the python standard library or pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not resist the itch so here is my approach.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import io

import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import string_types


def iter_fields(buf):
    for l in buf:
        yield l.rstrip('\n\r').split(':', 1)


def iter_messages(buf):
    it = iter_fields(buf)
    k, v = next(it)
    while True:
        n = int(v)
        _, v = next(it)
        date = pd.Timestamp(v)
        _, v = next(it)
        from_add, from_name, from_comp = v.split('|')[:-1]
        k, v = next(it)
        to = []
        while k == 'To':
            to_add, to_name, to_comp = v.split('|')[:-1]
            yield (n, date, from_add[1:], from_name[1:-1], from_comp,
                   to_add[1:], to_name[1:-1], to_comp)
            k, v = next(it)

    if not hasattr(filepath_or_buffer, read):
        filepath_or_buffer


def _read_email_headers(buf):
    columns=['email_message#', 'email_message_sent',
             'from_address', 'from_name', 'from_company',
             'to_address', 'to_name', 'to_company']
    return pd.DataFrame(iter_messages(buf), columns=columns)


def read_email_headers(path_or_buf):
    close_buf = False
    if isinstance(path_or_buf, string_types):
        path_or_buf = io.open(path_or_buf)
        close_buf = True
    try:
        return _read_email_headers(path_or_buf)
    finally:
        if close_buf:
            path_or_buf.close
```

This is how you would use it:

```
df = read_email_headers('.../data_file')
```

Just call it with the path to your file and you have your dataframe.

Now, **what follows is for test purposes only. You wouldn't do this to work with your actual data in the real life.**

Since I (or a random StackOverflow reader) do not have a copy of your file, I have to fake it using a string:

```
text = '''email_message#: 1
email_message_sent: 10/10/1991 02:31:01
From: tomf@abc.com| Tom Foo |abc company|
To: adee@abc.com| Alex Dee |abc company|
To: benfor12@xyz.com| Ben For |xyz company|
email_message#: 2
email_message_sent: 10/12/1991 01:28:12
From: timt@abc.com| Tim Tee |abc company|
To: tomf@abc.com| Tom Foo |abc company|
To: adee@abc.com| Alex Dee |abc company|
To: benfor12@xyz.com| Ben For|xyz company|'''
```

Then I can create a file-like object and pass it to the function:

```
df = read_email_headers(io.StringIO(text))
print(df.to_string())

   email_message#  email_message_sent  from_address from_name from_company        to_address   to_name   to_company
0               1 1991-10-10 02:31:01  tomf@abc.com   Tom Foo  abc company      adee@abc.com  Alex Dee  abc company
1               1 1991-10-10 02:31:01  tomf@abc.com   Tom Foo  abc company  benfor12@xyz.com   Ben For  xyz company
2               2 1991-10-12 01:28:12  timt@abc.com   Tim Tee  abc company      tomf@abc.com   Tom Foo  abc company
3               2 1991-10-12 01:28:12  timt@abc.com   Tim Tee  abc company      adee@abc.com  Alex Dee  abc company
4               2 1991-10-12 01:28:12  timt@abc.com   Tim Tee  abc company  benfor12@xyz.com    Ben Fo  xyz company
```

Or, if I wanted to work with an actual file:

```
with io.open('test_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)

df = read_email_headers('test_file.txt')
print(df.to_string())  # Same output as before.
```

But, again, **you do not have to do this to use the function with your data**. Just call it with a file path.

Comment: I understand the itch. This works for my example so I gave you the upvote but setting text and columns manually would not scale well for my solution.

Comment: I am afraid I did not make my point clear enough. I edited my answer to show how you are supposed to use it. Of course you are not expected to copy the content of the file in a string, that is just for testing. In the previous version you had had to open the file and pass the file object to a function. No I wrote a function which does it for you so you can just pass the file name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the absolute best way to do this. You're certainly not overlooking an obvious one-liner, which may reassure you.

It looks like your current parser (call it `my_parse`) does all the processing. In pseudocode:

```
finished_df = my_parse(original_text_file)
```

However, for such a large file, this is a little like cleaning up after a hurricane using tweezers. a two-stage solution may be faster, where you first roughly hew the file into the structure you want, then use pandas series operations to refine the rest. Continuing the pseudocode, you could do something like the following:

```
rough_df = rough_parse(original_text_file)
finished_df = refine(rough_df)
```

Where `rough_parse` uses Python standard-library stuff, and `refine` uses pandas series operations, particularly the [Series.str methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/api.html#string-handling).

I would suggest that the main goal of `rough_parse` would be simply to achieve a one-email--one-row structure. So basically you'd go through and replace all newline characters with some sort of unique delimiter that appears nowhere else in the file like `"$%$%$"`, except where the next thing after the newline is `"email_message#:"`

Then Series.str is really good at wrangling the rest of the strings how you want them.